# doctrine persist php class which inherit doctrine entity

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, persist

Is it possible to have a php class which extends a doctrine entity and to persist it ?

example:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class A {
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="C", mappedBy="parents")
   */
  protected $children;
}

class B extends A {
...
}

class C {
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="A", inversedBy="children")
   */
  protected $parents;
}

$b = new B();
$em->persist($b);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible, this is called [inheritance mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html), but the child class has to be explicitly declared as `@Entity` and its mapping has to be explicitly defined as well (if the child class adds extra properties).

The most common form of inheritance mapping is *single table inheritance*, here is an example of such mapping from the Doctrine manual:

```php
namespace MyProject\Model;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"person" = "Person", "employee" = "Employee"})
 */
class Person
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Employee extends Person
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Unfortunately we can not use inheritance mapping because we need to have associations to the parent class. Inheritance mapping does not work well with association in the parent class...

Comment: What do you mean by "association in the parent class"? Please give an example!

Comment: That should work equally well; what may require some work in your domain model, is to keep consistency. That is, A::addChild() should call C::addParent(), and/or vice-versa. Doctrine will not do this magic for you. But this is outside the scope of your original question, for which the answer is yes, you can.

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#performance-impact

 Doctrine documentation says: There is a general performance consideration with Single Table Inheritance: If the target-entity of a many-to-one or one-to-one association is an STI entity, it is preferable for performance reasons that it be a leaf entity in the inheritance heirarchy, (ie. have no subclasses). Otherwise Doctrine CANNOT create proxy instances of this entity and will ALWAYS load the entity eagerly.

Comment: Normally it's not a big problem because if I load A or B, C will be load. Because C has a proxy nothing else will be load. But in my Schema I also have a OneToMany relation between two B. So if I load a B object, which does not have any Proxy, all B will be loaded plus all C. It's a big performance issue...

Comment: i dont think STI is a problem in your case, because you use ManyToMany. The problem comes with OneToOne and ManyToOne only, when you try to fetch from the inverse side. Then a huge performance problem appears - doctrine starts a set of selects for each entry in the database(one select per entry). In such case you either change your logic or use custom select with joins.