# Doctrine many repository for same entity

Tags: php, doctrine, repository, entity

is it possible to have two repositories for the same entity ?

I try something like that, but it does not work..

```
class PackageRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function __construct($em, Mapping\ClassMetadata $class)
    {
        $cmf = $em->getMetadataFactory();
        $class = $cmf->getMetadataFor('Product');
        parent::__construct($em, $class);
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, why would you want to do that?

Second, to answer your question. You can have as many repositories working with same entities as you like, they are just simple classes after all.

But you can link only one class with the entity class using the @Repository annotation (or YAML, or XML, whatever). All the mapping data is stored in the EntityManager. EntityManager will know only one repository class is linked with the entity class, if you try to get it with `$entity->getReposiotry()` or similar it will return only the linked class.

But nothing can stop you from creating your own classes which do some queries and call them directly, explicitly, without relying on the EntityManagers repository mapping.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need it because I have an entity which represent actually two classes. I didn't find how to solve this problem with Inheritance. It's another Problem which is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501755/doctrine-persist-php-class-which-inherit-doctrine-entity

Comment: I actually wanted to know, in the case of a Repository specific to Administration methods and operations, and a Repository specific to Frontend methods and operations, that manage the same Entity.  Too bad theres no way to dictate which Repository can be used based on Access path.

Comment: "But nothing can stop you from creating your own classes which do some queries and call them directly, explicitly, without relying on the EntityManagers repository mapping."
Do you have an example to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

I also have run into the same issue, when two Symfony bundles work with same entity, but queries are different for each bundle, so I also decided create separate repository for each bundle. For **Doctrine 2** the solution can be:

1. "@Repository annotation" can be used to point default repository or just avoid it.
2. Create usual [repository class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html), e.g. "MyEntityRepository".
3. In code:

   `$myEntityRepo = new MyEntityRepository($entityManager, $entityManager->getClassMetadata('AppBundle:MyEntity'));`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Something in PHP called `Trait`.

Example:

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository {

   public function adminQuery1();
   public function adminQuery2();
   public function adminQuery3();
   public function adminQuery4();
   public function adminQuery5();
   public function adminQuery6();    

   public function frontEndQuery1();
   public function frontEndQuery2(); 
   public function frontEndQuery3(); 
   public function frontEndQuery4(); 
   public function frontEndQuery5(); 
   public function frontEndQuery6();     
}
```

Now keep on going with different specific query portions and your repository quickly becomes confusing and too long. 
You could

1. Create multiple repository that inherit each other OR
2. Use traits

Example Below:

```
Trait AdminQuery {
   public function adminQuery1();
   public function adminQuery2();
   public function adminQuery3();
   public function adminQuery4();
   public function adminQuery5();
   public function adminQuery6();    
}

Trait FrontEndQuery {
   public function adminQuery1();
   public function adminQuery2();
   public function adminQuery3();
   public function adminQuery4();
   public function adminQuery5();
   public function adminQuery6();    
}
```

The actual repository class.

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository {
   use AdminQuery;
   use FrontEndQuery;      
}
```

The beauty of this is that the keyword `this` will refer to the context in which the the `Trait` was used meaning you have access to all functions of `EntityRepository`

Finally found a use case for `Trait`.

Comment: And what with referring to `$this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery()` from the level of trait? Your IDE will have no idea about EM.

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom entity repository which can be autowired in Symfony, you just need:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class MyEntityRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $class = $em->getClassMetadata(MyEntity::class);
        parent::__construct($em, $class);
    }
}
```